# MS Word 2010: Can't Preset the ControlSource property of a textbox

Tags: vba, textbox, ms-word, userform

Really simple question for MS Word 2010 users.

I want to preset the value of a textbox in a userform with a template property. What value am I supposed to put into here? ("docproperty" is a string, but I also need to populate other textboxes with numbers.)

[image: ControlSource in textbox properties]

I've tried Application.Templates(1).CustomDocumentProperties("docproperty").value, Application.Templates("Normal.dotm").CustomDocumentProperties("docproperty").value, docproperty, =docproperty, { docproperty }, and a whole myriad of things, but I keep getting: "Could not get the ControlSource property. Invalid property value."

Every Google site I hit tells me how to do it in Excel, but from a range of cells, not from Word from a template property. Any help would be amazing!

Comment: I'm afraid Word doesn't support the ControlSource property for textboxes. As I recall, this only works in Excel. But since all the Office applications share the same UserForms type library ("Forms 2.0"), you see the property in Word, as well...

Comment: Ah. Ok. Well, that takes care of that. I have alternatives, but thanks Cindy!